# simple way to git merge current branch into other branch

Tags: git

Is there a standard technical term for a git merge operation that works in the opposite direction, that is, merges the current branch into the other? I mean this:

```
git checkout $BRANCH_TO_MERGE_FROM
git checkout --detach $BRANCH_TO_MERGE_INTO
git merge -
git checkout -B $BRANCH_TO_MERGE_FROM
```

Also, is there a way to achieve this which 1-2 commands?

The use case is when we're working on master and need to do a non-ff merge into origin/master.

Edit: so it's important that the merge commit's first parent must be the commit on origin/master before the merge.

Comment: Why not just check out the other branch, and merge your current branch? I'm sure I'm missing something here so clarifying your question would be useful.

Comment: because they have the same name: we're working on the local master and want to merge into origin/master. `git checkout master` does nothing.

Comment: `git checkout origin/master`? I should point out if you are going to push this that the remote will only take ff merges.

Comment: yes, `git checkout origin/master` is the same as what I wrote (`git checkout --detach $BRANCH_TO_MERGE_INTO`)...what I wrote does work. It's only I wonder if there's some git-magic-op which does my 3 lines in one command.

Comment: While that doesn't directly answer your question, have you thought about using `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: Yes, in my use case rebasing is the first option. But sometimes we don't want to rebase and in that case we need this. My current task is to provide the other developers, who are not so good at git, some robust and easy to remember best practices in order to get rid of the spaghetti history they've been doing so far. Rebasing could be complicated in certain cases and in that cases I want them to do such a git-merge-into operation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it would be (with "`--no-ff`", since "need to do a non-ff merge"):

```
git pull --no-ff
git push
```

That would merge `origin/master` into `master`, and, after pushing, update `origin/master`.
No need to try and merge `master` to `origin/master`.

Comment: `git pull` merges the other branch into the current branch, so it creates a commit whose first parent is my local commit, which is undesirable. That's why I need to do the opposite, merging my branch into the remote. I edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: @tamas.kenez I understood that, but I never seen a merge in that way.